# compability of data types between java client and wcf service

Tags: wcf, types, java-client

I am developing a `WCF Service` application with `basicHttpBinding` option. I chosed `basicHttpBinding` because my client could be a Java client, a Visual Basic Client etc. 
Now i want to be sure that the datatypes which i used in my application are compatible and consumable with Java clients or other platform languages. 
For instance, Which of the following .NET datatypes can be used without affacting interoperatablitiy?

- DateTime
- int
- double
- double?
- float
- float?
- string

Comment: isnt there anyone to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.
I found a resource which tells the interoperability of data types between .Net server and Java client.

[The documantation](http://java.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/data-types-interoperability-between-net-and-java#h5Section0)

The documantation says that using nullable data types wont make any headache to developers. However, i wont use nullable datatypes like `double?` `int?` etc. I will assing default values insead.